# How to do time lapse with bracketing burst?

Tags: hdr, timelapse, bracketing

I am starting a project and I'd like to do some sunset time lapse. Each frame of the time lapse should be an HDR image. So, I need a bracketing burst every X minutes during a given period of time. Is there any way or application (such as digiCamControl) which allows to automate the whole process? 
Thanks,

Dani

Comment: What camera are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should've said that: Nikon D300

Comment: Check this link - has links that are relevant for both equip and technique - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/are-intervalometers-different-for-standard-time-lapse-and-hdr-time-lapse?rq=1

Comment: Someone flagged this as off-topic as a product recommendation question. I don't think that this falls into the reasons we discourage such questions. It's true that a product recommendation might be part of the answer, but the question is _how to do it_, and that's on-topic.

Comment: You're right. I'm asking for techniques.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @BShaw's answer, if you're a Mac/Aperture user the following blog post might help:

http://www.crystal-objects.com/blogs/frank/time_lapsed_photography_aperture_using_applescript050911

It's a script to take a specified number of photographs at a chosen interval between them. I have used the script successfully to create time-lapse videos. My guess is, if you set your D300 to bracket the exposure, then set the script running while your camera is tethered, it should take the appropriate exposures if the interval between shots is long enough.

This may or may not help, but is another option at least.